# Keep/transfer material ID with Replicate Mesh Data animation node

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, animation-nodes

How can I keep/transfer material ID when I replicate a mesh with animation node(Replicate Mesh Data)?

Using Blender 2.78a on Windows machine with latest Animation Nodes Addon - Cython Branch

[image: Nodes]

[image: Base Mesh]

Comment: this is not possible yet. remember, the cython branch is still in development. Not sure yet how it will work in the future, sorry.

Comment: @JacquesLucke Should probably post that as the answer, not a comment.

Comment: Thanks @JacquesLucke for the prompt reply, does your answer imply that it could be achieved with another version of animation-nodes?
Thanks Again